# Error 404 when routing

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to do my site like this tutorial http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

but have some problem with routing. I have page "createBook" for default and when I call localhost it's work! But when I do like localhost/createBook I have Error 404. What I'm doing wrong?

**In my controller:**

```
    public function view($page = 'createBook')
{
        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
        }
        $this->load->view($page);
}
```

**routes.php file**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Books/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'Books/view/$1';
```

And I have view files in my views folder named Success and createBook

Comment: did u modified your htaccess?

Comment: no. What I must do in htaccess?

Comment: if u want to use `$route['(:any)']` than y r u using `$route['default_controller']` note that, this will hurt your other urls, suppose, u have contactus.php when you try to open contactus page book page will open

Comment: I dont understant you. Please, make it like answer, what I must change in htaccess and other

Comment: use small letters

Comment: still 404, but when I just put localhost without parameters(in my method createBook is default) it works! Open createBook view.

Comment: what happened, if u try this `$route['mybook/(:any)'] = 'Books/view/$1';` and url `localhost/mybook/createBook`

Comment: I need to create mybook folder in views folder to that?

Comment: no need, u r using routes

Comment: no,it doesnt work:(

Comment: `Books` is your controller name right?

Comment: in controller folder I have Books.php which extends CI_Controller

Comment: use `echo $page; exit;` before this line `if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/'.$page.'.php'))` and share the reuslt

Comment: I insert this code but have 404 error too

Comment: Maybe its wrong parameter?Maybe I must put parameter something else?

Comment: may be .... . ...

Comment: when I just use localhost echo works, but if another request its 404

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your question but it seems to me that you are trying to call a controller named createBook from the url, but in your function it shows that if there is no views/createBook.php than show 404, maybe its why you get a 404, because your calling a controller as a view, **i think your function should be like this** :

```
public function view($page = 'createBook')
{
  if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/' . $page . '.php'))
    {
     // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
     $this->output->set_status_header('404');
     show_404();
    }
  $this->load->view($page);
}
```

If you want your url to look something like this :

```
example.com/view/book/3
```

**Your controller** should look like this :

```
class View extends CI_Controller 
{
  public function book($book_id) 
    {
     //Search the database for records about a book with its id, and return the data
     //and assign it to a variable(in this case $data) ex : $data["book-name"] = ...
     //And on your view you can call these values using ex : echo $book-name
     $this->load->view('books_view', $data);
    }
}
```

And make sure your .**htaccess** file next to the index.php looks like something like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Then go to your config, and change this line to :

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Now you can access all of your controllers this way :

```
http://www.example.com/controller_name
```